# C# generics where clause with inheritance and interfaces

Tags: c#

I have a class I want to be generic, where `T` is restricted to any derived type of `Fruit`. I also want the class to derive from another class, and implement an interface. Unfortunately, I can't work out the syntax. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
public abstract class Food<T> where T : Fruit, BaseClass, IInterface {}
```

The idea is specialized classes of `Food<T>` can only be objects that are derived from `Fruit` for `T`, such as `Apple : Fruit => Food<Apple>`, or `Orange : Fruit => Food<Orange>`, and I also want `Food<T>` to inherit `BaseClass` and implement members of `IInterface`.

Currently it is a syntax error and I do not know how to correctly write it out. How can I do this?

Comment: "So the idea is, derived classes of `Food<T>`..." I think you misunderstood what a generic constraint is for. `T: Fruit` constraints `T`, not the derived classes of `Food`. You can't control what the subclasses of `Food` do.

Comment: Do you mean that `T` should inherit from `Fruit`, while `Food` should inherit `BaseClass` and implement `IInterface`?

Comment: @Sweeper maybe i worded it wrong, but basically if i create a new `Food` it would only accept types that are of `Fruit` such as `new Food<Apple>();` or `new Food<Orange>();`

Comment: I see, what about `BaseClass` and `IInterface`? How are they related?

Comment: BaseClass is just a base class that Food inherits from and Interface i need for polymorphism for some inventory system later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but this at least compiles:

```
public class BaseClass {}
public interface IInterface{}

public class Fruit {}
public class Apple : Fruit {}
public class Orange : Fruit {}

public class Food<T> : BaseClass, IInterface where T : Fruit {}
```

Comment: To maybe clarify what OP was asking; I found myself in a situation where I wanted to create a class that does two things: 1. Inherit functionality from a Collection class, and 2. Pass a constrained generic up to the inherited Collection. I think your answer hit the nail on the head; Inherited classes come first in the syntax, generic constraints come after.

Answer (score 1):

A [class declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#class-declarations) has the following syntax:

```
class_declaration
    : attributes? class_modifier* 'partial'? 'class' identifier type_parameter_list?
      class_base? type_parameter_constraints_clause* class_body ';'?
    ;
class_base
    : ':' class_type
    | ':' interface_type_list
    | ':' class_type ',' interface_type_list
    ;

interface_type_list
    : interface_type (',' interface_type)*
    ;
type_parameter_constraints_clause
    : 'where' type_parameter ':' type_parameter_constraints
    ;
```

Since you want `Food` to implement `IInterface` and inherit from `BaseClass`, they are part of the `class_base` specification, not the `type_parameter_constraints_clause` (the part with the word `where`) that comes after.

From the syntax, you can see that the `class_base` would go before the word `where`:

```
public abstract class Food<T>: BaseClass, IInterface where T : Fruit {}
```

Comment: Great explanation, class syntax declaration order is important.

Answer (score 0):

It means "food implements iinterface, and t can only descend from fruit":

```
public abstract class Food<T> : IInterface
  where T : Fruit  {}
```

If you want "t can only descend from fruit or baseclass", make a parent class that fruit and baseclass descend from and `where` that. If you mean that Food descends from baseclass, put it in the first line with a comma. The general pattern is:

```
class X<T,U,...> : ImplementsOrIs,These,Classes,Or,Interfaces
  where T : IsAssignableToThisSingleType
  where U : IsAssignableToThisSingleType
  ...
```